# Ionic loading on full page instead of small box

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

At this moment I can use this kind of simple [loading](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/loading/LoadingController/) effect. But it shows as a small box.

```
presentLoadingText() {
  let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
     content: 'Loading Please Wait...'
  });

  loading.present();    

}
```

But I have a task to create full-page loader like so.

[image]

It should be full page and have background black with a transparent appearance like above. No need that wave effect. Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working solution for me. I have targeted `loading-wrapper`.

*app.scss*

```
.loading-wrapper {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-width: 100% !important;
    max-height: 100% !important;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) !important;
}
```

.ts

```
 let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content:
        `<div class="custom-spinner-container">
        Please wait...
      </div>`,
    });
    loader.present();
```

UI:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have already that so you can do it with help of css.

### html

```
this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    spinner: 'spinner',
    content: `
    <div class="login_view">
        <div class="loader_view">
            <div class="cst_loader"></div>
        </div>
    </div>`,
    showBackdrop: showBackdrop
});
this.loading.present();
```

### ts

```
.login_view{
    background: url(../../assets/imgs/login_bg.png) no-repeat 100% 100%;
    background-size: contain;
}
.loader_view{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Can't we use transparent background (css) instead of an image?

Comment: I think you can use it just remove background image and check because in my case I have image.

Comment: I have used like this `.login_view {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
}`. But it is not working. Any clue?

Comment: I think you have to give height and width 100% 100%

Comment: That too not working.  I can see that those styles were applied on the dev tools. But no effect. Can you share an image of your screen? Image too not working for me?